# How to control the form size expansion without events

Tags: windows, c#-4.0

I have a windows form with 6 `textboxes`. On the form load, by default, only one `textbox` will be  displayed with the form size reduced. Once i enter the text into the `textbox`, my form size should increase and should display second `textbox` without any button click or `textbox events`. The intention behind it is that user doesn't put any extra effort to click button as it should be user friendly. Is there any possible ways of doing it?

Comment: Hey..Can you put your code here..?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is impossible to do it without events, but possible without button clicks (which are actually producing events which should be handled)

So the most user friendly thing you can do is using events and where is no reason to avoid them. To achieve your functionality you have to

a) Set the `Autosize` property of the form to `true`

b) Handle the `TextChanged` event of your only textbox with following code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(((TextBox)sender).Text.Length > 0)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged);
        this.Controls.Add(tb);
    }
}
```